# Añadir +1 al mes en el calendario

Tags: java, android

Tengo un problema con los *meses*, ya sé que enero es **0** y por lo tanto hay que añadir **+1** en el *mes*, pero lo hago y sigue igual, ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

*Así es mi código:*

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
// 1/03 por defecto
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
```

*Y así es como pongo el **+1**:*

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
// 1/03 por defecto
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, +1, 3);
```

**EDITO 1:**

Lo que realizo es que al escribir en un *EditText* una fecha, la notificación se envía ese día, pero como comento arriba no funcionan correctamente los meses.

Si escribo por ejemplo 12/05 (Fecha de hoy) no se envía la notificación, pero si escribo 12/04 (mes pasado) si se envía correctamente la notificación.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public void setAlarm(Context context) {
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5);

    Log.i(TAG, context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + "05/05 (default)");

    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);

    // Enable {@code SampleBootReceiver} to automatically restart the alarm when the
    // device is rebooted.
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}

public void setAlarm(Context context, String date, int idPersona) {
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + date);
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmReceiver.class);

        /** Obtiene datos para enviar en bundle **/
        intent.putExtra( "notification_id", idPersona);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        Persona persona = baseDatos.getPersona(idPersona);
        intent.putExtra("nombre", persona.getNombre());
        intent.putExtra("idPersona", persona.getId());
        intent.putExtra("fecha", persona.getFecha());


        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, idPersona, intent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

      String myDate[] = date.split("/");

        Log.i(TAG, "calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, " + myDate[0]);
        Log.i(TAG, "calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, " + myDate[1]);

        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(myDate[0]));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(myDate[1]));

        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);

        // Enable {@code SampleBootReceiver} to automatically restart the alarm when the
        // device is rebooted.
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "setAlarm() " + e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Obtener la descripción del més actual.

Para obtener el més actual en forma de texto puedes usar:

```
Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String mesActual = mCalendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
```

Te recomiendo configurar un [LOCALE](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) adecuado para que se muestre en tu idioma por ejemplo:

```
 Locale localeSpanish = new Locale("es", "ES");
String mesActual = mCalendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, localeSpanish);
```

el resultado sería: `mayo`

#### Obtener el mes actual en forma numerica.

Si deseas el número del més debes sumar 1:

```
Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int month = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
```

---

En el caso de tu código, obtienes los valores de día y mes en un array, lo que tienes que realizar es sumar +1 para agregar o -1 para restar en el caso del més:

```
 calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(myDate[1]) + 1);
```

Comment: Si añado el +1 como me comentas, el mes 5 pasa a ser Julio :(, por defecto el mes 5 es Junio, así que al añadir +1 pasa a ser Julio, pero el mes 5 debe ser Mayo y en vez de ponerle +1, le he puesto -1 y ahora el mes si está bien, el problema es que por defecto tenía un mes de más, es la forma correcta poner -1 o hay una mejor?  Gracias @Jorgesys

Comment: De hecho como es un valor entero puedes agregar 1 para un més más o -1 para restar.

Comment: Pues solucionado, gracias @Jorgesys !

Comment: Excelente! saludos! ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ

Answer (score 1):

Te estás confundiendo.

Lo que dice la documentación es que `Calendar` cuenta a partir de 0: Enero es el mes 0, Febrero el 1.... Diciembre el 11. Pero, con una excepción, ese es un detalle interno y no necesitas hacer nada para que `Calendar` "funcione".

La excepción es cuando obtengas o asignes el mes, debes de tener el que el número de mes empieza a contar a partir de 0 para saber identificar el valor.

Por ejemplo:

```
switch (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
case 0:
  System.out.println("Enero");
...
}
```

o, para asignar Mayo:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 4);
```

Para hacerlo más fácil de leer, `Calendar` incluye los meses como constantes (en inglés, claro): `Calendar.JANUARY`,  `Calendar.FEBRUARY`.

Comment: El problema es que creo una alarma en un edittext, escribo la fecha, por ejemplo 12/05 y no se activa hoy, pero si escribo 12/04, si se activa hoy.. @SJuan76

Comment: ¿Has leído la parte de "para asignar Mayo..."? ¿Qué valor paso para Mayo? En todo caso, no hay ningún método de Calendar al que le puedas pasar `String`; si quieres más información sobre el problema pon el código necesario para poder reproducirlo.

Comment: He editado la pregunta para ver si así se me enciende mejor, gracias por la ayuda @SJuan76

Comment: La respuesta es la misma. Nosotros contamos los meses a partir de 1. `Calendar` los cuenta a partir de 0. Si quieres pasar un mes de "humano" a `Calendar`, hay que restar 1. Al revés, hay que sumar 1.

Answer (score 0):

Para incrementar meses, días, horas, etc. puedes hacerlo apoyándote en el calendario, no obstante deberías dejar la lógica de sumar meses al propio calendario para evitar confusiones tanto con el código del mes inicial como al realizar el set de meses que no existen. Adjunto una función de ejemplo que puedes utilizar para incrementar meses:

```
private Date addMonth(Date date, int amount){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, amount);

    return calendar.getTime();
}
```